# Openpyxl check for empty cell

Tags: python, object, comparison, openpyxl

`openpyxl` seems to be a great method for using *Python* to read *Excel* files, but I've run into a constant problem. I need to detect whether a cell is empty or not, but can't seem to compare any of the cell properties. I tried casting as a string and using `""` but that didn't work. The type of cell when it is empty is `None`, or `NoneType` but I can't figure out how to compare an object to that.

Suggestions? I understand `openpyxl` is under development, but maybe this is more a general *Python* problem.

Comment: Once again, a little more searching has yielded the answer: use `if cell.value is None`

Comment: If(type(cell.value) is type(None)) works for me....

Answer (score 34):

To do something when cell is not empty add:

```
if cell.value:
```

which in python is the same as if cell value is not None (i.e.: if not cell.value == None:)

Note to avoid checking empty cells you can use

```
worksheet.get_highest_row()
```

and

```
worksheet.get_highest_column()
```

Also I found it useful (although might not be a nice solution) if you want to use the contents of the cell as a string regardless of type you can use:

```
unicode(cell.value)
```

Comment: **Watch out!** `bool(cell.values) == False` if `cell.value = 0`

Comment: In newest openpyxl, which has removed get_highest_row and get_highest_column method. They have been replaced by max_row and max_column property

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Checking this way will treat zeros as empty cells.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me.

```
if cell.value is None:
    print("Blank")
else:
    print("Not Blank")
```

Comment: is there a command-line shortcut that you guys know that can replace blank cells with ""? THANK YOU!

Comment: I have a worksheet, where the cell looks blank, both `bool(not cell.value is None)` and `bool(not cell.value == None)` give True,  but `print(cell.value)` gives nothing, and `print(len(cell.value))` gives 0, totally confusing

Answer (score 4):

The

```
if cell.value is None:
```

is the best option to use for this case.

if you wish to use it in an iteration, you can use it like this:

```
ws=wb.active
names=ws['C']
for x in names:
    if x.value is None:
        break
    print(x.value)
```

The problem with `ws.max_column` and `ws.max_row` is that it will count blank columns as well, thus defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cell or cells you wish to validate 
Also you can code, for example:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

if sheet.cell(row = 1, column=7).value == None:
    print("Blank") 
else:
    print("No blank")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was compare with None as String

```
if cell(row,col).value == "None":
    print(" Ignore cell ... ")
```