# Get empty cell coordinates with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I work at a script to extract some very messy data from a huge excel file and I run into a bump. 
There is any way to get coordinates from an empty cell with openpyxl?

This will return an error saying EmptyCell has no row/column attribute

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.column is ... :
           print(cell.value)
```

I cannot skip the empty cells, as there are empty cells in some columns that have to taken into account and extracted as such in the new file.
Also, I cannot fill the empty cells because the original file is huge and its opened read only because of this.

There is any way to do this with openpyxl or I should try to use another library?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907928/openpyxl-check-for-empty-cell

Comment: If you google it, you'll get more answers.

Comment: I found that topic and is about finding empty cells... That is not helpfull  because I needed the coordinates of the empty cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EmptyCell's are special cells in the read-only context: they are fillers created where there are no cells in the original XML so that rows from a range are of equal length. As such they do not really exist and hence do not have coordinates. If you need their coordinates then you can simply use `enumerate` to count for you while looping.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, that will do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows():  
       for cell in row:  
        if cell.value is None :  
           print(str(cell.column)+str(cell.row))
```