# Openpyxl - Remove formatting from all sheets in an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have files with a lot of weird formatting and I'm trying to create a function that removes any formatting from an xlsx file.

Some guys in here suggested to use "cell.fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None)" to clear any format from a given cell.

```
path = r'C:\Desktop\Python\Openpyxl\Formatted.xlsx
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename = path)

def removeFormatting(file):
    ws = wb[file]
    
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value is None:
                cell.fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None)

    wb.save(path)

for s in wb.sheetnames:
    removeFormatting(s)
```

But this won't change anything. If the cells are empty but colored, then openpyxl still sees them as non empty.

Following this post:
[Openpyxl check for empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907928/openpyxl-check-for-empty-cell)

> The problem with ws.max_column and ws.max_row is that it will count blank columns as well, thus defeating the purpose."

@bhaskar was right.
When I'm trying to get the max column, I get for all the sheets, the same value as from the first sheet.

```
col = []    
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        col.append(sheet.max_column)
```

So even if there are different sheet dimensions, if the cell has a background color or any other formatting, it will take it as valid non empty cell.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just assign the default style to every cell.

Comment: @CharlieClark Can you please clarify? I thought that doing the loop, does cover all the cells in the sheet. What would be the default style like?

Comment: Whatever you want it to be but using a named style is the quickest way to do this. Don't worry about whether the cells are there or not.

Comment: @CharlieClark I'm super sorry but can you please give me an example?

Comment: @CharlieClark How do I assign the default style?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function removes styles from all cells in a given worksheet (passed as `ws` object).
So you can open your file, iterate over all worksheets and apply this function to each one:

```
def removeFormatting(ws):
    # ws is not the worksheet name, but the worksheet object
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            cell.style = 'Normal'
```

If you also want to check info about how to define and apply named styles, take a look here:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#cell-styles-and-named-styles